# Reading raw, unencoded content of file(bytes)

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io, arrays

I have a mission to make a "stamp creator" for Powder Toy. The "stamp" looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcOeF.jpg . I'd like to use the bytes' values for my creator. For that I need to read the unencoded content of the file. Any help? Also, I'll need to create such content as well. (Maybe I'm better off using a byte[] array?(but how to enter the special control characters?))

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to read the file, and [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) to write it back.

If you need more control instead of reading an entire file into memory, you can use [`File.OpenRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) and [`File.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx) to read and write using a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx). If you do that make sure you dispose of it - using the `using` keyword is encouraged.

Here are a couple of examples

```
public void CopyFileByReadingItAllToMemory() {
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\input");
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\output", data);
}

public void CopyFileWithoutReadingItAllToMemory() {
    using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\input"))
    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Temp\output"))
    {
        while (true) {
            int value = input.ReadByte();
            if (value == -1) {
                break;
            }

            output.WriteByte((byte)value);
        }
    }
}
```